# 5,6,7,8 Generated JS files of Angular 4+ App when building prod

Tags: angular, build

[image]

Anyone has an idea why prod build of angular app is generating these files and what are they for?

Comment: Those are bundle files of your modules and components.

Comment: based on my research prod build generates files like main, polyfill, styles etc. I'm not sure why they are named 5,6,7,8 and what are they for. I have main, polyfill files generated as well but with explicit names.